# Changing the password column name and logging in (Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I changed the password column name to `sha_pass_hash` and now I get an undefined index error when attempting to login.

> ErrorException
> Undefined index: sha_pass_hash

Does anyone know what needs to be edited to get this changed around to work as intended?

Comment: Why are you changing the name, and why are you using SHA for password hashing?